# DEP (/NXCOMPAT) causing segfault in LoadLibrary (down in DllMainCRTStartup)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dep

In this case I do have the source for both the application and the dll.

When both are compiled *without* /NXCOMPAT, they work together fine.  But when I compile both *with* /NXCOMPAT, I get a segfault deep in kernelspace.

If I compile the dll with /NXCOMPAT, and compile the executable without, it also works fine.  (not surprising I suppose, since the DEP settings for the executable get forced on the loaded dll.)

I have previously seen a segfault in MainCRTStartup (Note: not the dll version), after enabling DEP, which was caused by another linker option.  However, in this case that other linker option is NOT set, so I know that's not the answer.

Anyone have an idea where I should look for the cause?

Edit: Further strangeness.  I've been running this in the debugger in VS 2008 the whole time, but when I tried running it without the debugger attached, the segfault disappears.  I find this a very unsatisfactory solution, as I still don't know *why* it's been doing this.

Edit the 2nd: Also segfaults running in the debugger in VS 2013 Express.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking code, we have to guess by the symptoms. My crystal ball says you're doing things inside `LoadLibrary` (i.e. inside `DllMainCRTStartup`) which are banned. And there is a very long list of things which are banned in `LoadLibrary`, including loading any other DLL.

Note that your global objects are created from `DllMainCRTStartup` and therefore have to respect the `LoadLibrary` rules as well.

Comment: If I were doing something banned in DllMainCRTStartup, I'd expect a crash even without DEP active.  And even if it was something banned by DEP, why would _that_ only crash _with a debugger attached?!?_  That's the part that has me really confused.

Comment: @jbcarpen: That's the classical problem with Undefined Behavior. If the failure mode would have been consistent, it probably would have been easy to detect and specifically report the problem.